# GIT - HEAD one commit ahead

Tags: git

I have the following message:

`fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.`

when trying to do `GIT PULL`

I did `GIT REBASE` and it works to PULL remote commits to the branches, but HEAD still not pointing to the branches!?

I would like to merge the commit ahead to the branches.
(PRODUCTION SERVER)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my case doing the following:

```
$git checkout –b temp #makes a new branch from current detached HEAD
$git branch –f master temp #update master to point to the new <temp> branch
$git branch –d temp #delete the <temp> branch
$git push origin master #push the re-established history
```

Both branches are now merged with HEAD.